# How to invoke node package manager from Sublime Text 2

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2, npm

How I can invoke node package manager from Sublime Text 2? I would like to install/uninstall packages from Sublime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I use [Sublime Terminal Plugin](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal) and do npm install , or npm install -save "package"  if i had .json package created.